# Ebyte NS1 Design question

Tags: pcb, ethernet, rj45

I am working on a new design  dev board base on stm32h750 and Ebyte NS1 Ethernet Module .

Ebyte give 2 design in data sheet .

1 one with a filter HR641680E

2 with a RJ45 build in 2KV electromagnetic isolation transformer.

I have in my stock HANRUN HR911105A , how to test this rj45 to be sure that this RJ45 terminal has the 2kv isolation transformer ("the datasheet of the rj45 tell yes").

last question what is the best design for a normal ethernet use?